# Ubuntu upgrade failure end up to partly installed 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I have tried to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10. I have used the command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

without knowing that it will install development release. Now I end up installing 16.04. During the upgrade my laptop monitor was not working, I didn't know whether the upgrade was complete or not. I have rebooted the system, I end up with 16.04 cmd line login prompt and network also not working. Please help me to update to stable 15.10.

Thanks in Advance,
Baskar

Comment: Your title says 15.04, your question says 15.10. In any case, your best bet is to back up your data with an installer USB/DVD and reinstall.

Comment: @Zacharee1 the title even now says 16.04. I'm confused

Comment: Well you can't upgrade down/downgrade Ubuntu, at least not in a stable manner. You need to reinstall to get 15.10